# Deriving the likelihood-ratio test statistic for a normal distribution with unknown mean and variance

Tags: normal-distribution, likelihood-ratio

In the wiki link for [likelihood-ratio tests](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood-ratio_test#), it states

> Suppose that we have a random sample, of size n, from a population
> that is normally-distributed. Both the mean, μ, and the standard
> deviation, σ, of the population are unknown. We want to test whether
> the mean is equal to a given value, μ0 .
>
> $${\displaystyle {\mathcal {L}}(\mu ,\sigma \mid x)=\left(2\pi \sigma^{2}\right)^{-n/2}\exp \left(-\sum _{i=1}^{n}{\frac {(x_{i}-\mu)^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}}\right)\,.}$$
>
> With some calculation (omitted here), it can then be shown that
>
> $$ {\displaystyle \lambda =\left(1+{\frac {t^{2}}{n-1}}\right)^{-n/2}}$$

Can someone show me the omitted calculations to get to this result for $\lambda$?

Comment: Write the maximizer of the likelihood under H0 and H1 and take their ratio, which is presumably what $\lambda$ is intended to be. Then simplify.

Answer (score 0):

There are no tricks here. Stick to the basic principles, as advised by 
[Glen_b](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/599102/deriving-the-likelihood-ratio-test-statistic-for-a-normal-distribution-with-unkn#comment1109508_599102). A general sketch as to how to proceed:

Let the hypotheses be $\mathcal H_0: \mu = \mu_0; ~0<\sigma^2<\infty$ against $\mathcal H_1: \mu \ne \mu_0; ~0<\sigma^2<\infty.$

$\bullet$ Restricted parameter space $\Theta_0 =\{(\mu_0,\sigma^2)\mid0<\sigma^2\infty\}.$

$\bullet$ The likelihood function is

$$\mathcal {L}=\left(2\pi \sigma^{2}\right)^{-n/2}\exp \left(-\sum _{i=1}^{n}{\frac {(x_{i}-\mu)^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}}\right).\tag 1\label 1$$

$\bullet$ It's easy to check mles of $\mu, \sigma^2$ as

\begin{align}\hat \mu &= \bar x\\ \hat\sigma^2&= \frac1n\sum _{i=1}^{n}(x_{i}-\hat\mu)^2:= s^2.\tag 2\label 2\end{align}

$\bullet$ In $\Theta_0,$

\begin{align} \hat\sigma^2&= \frac1n\sum _{i=1}^{n}(x_{i}-\bar x)^2+ (\bar x-\mu_0)^2:= s_0^2.\tag 3\label 3\end{align}

$\bullet$ Therefore

\begin{align}\lambda = \frac{\mathcal L\left(\hat\Theta_0\right)}{\mathcal L\left(\hat\Theta\right)}\\ &= \left(\frac{s^2}{s_0^2}\right)^{\frac n2}\\ &= \left(\frac{1}{1+ \left[\frac{(\bar x-\mu_0)^2}{s^2}\right]}\right)^{\frac n2}.\tag 4\label 4\end{align}

$\bullet$ Define \begin{align}S^2 := \frac{ns^2}{n-1},\\t := \frac{\sqrt{n}(\bar x - \mu_0)}{S};\end{align} substituting them in $\eqref 4$ yields

$$\lambda = \frac1{\left(1+{\frac {t^{2}}{n-1}}\right)^{\frac{n}2}}.\tag 5$$

$\bullet$ The corresponding LR test is thus based on $t\sim \mathsf t_{n-1}.$